# nodejs child_process.spawn return throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I wanna exec another `.js` file with child_process.spawn. I'm using OSX.
The code is :

```
var server = spawn( '/Path/to/node', /.../server.js' );
```

And it is failed with :

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn /Users/GB/Dev/workspace_fe/www_ms/output/node/server.js ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

It's working well if only with command in shell `/Path/to/node', /.../server.js`.

Answer (score 3):

According to [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) second argument of spawn must be array. Have you tried this:

```
var server = spawn( 'node', ['/path/to/server.js'] );
```